# how to track element through value of element using selenium ide?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests

I am testing a Website using selenium **IDE** and this site uses something called wickets that changes the element id of elements in some random fashion. There is a **drop-down list**  having some options but selenium is not recording anything about drop-down list. I tried doing it manually by Giving Target some to track the it by value

```
Command             |Target                    |Value
select              |//div[@id="duration3"]    |level=4 night (s)
```

Can I Solve it by value or option?

following is the snippet:
`<select id="duration3" name="facets:durations:duration" wicket:id="duration">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1 night(s)</option>
    <option value="2">2 night(s)</option>
    <option value="3">3 night(s)</option>
    <option value="4">4 night(s)</option>
    <option value="5">5 night(s)</option>
    <option value="6">6 night(s)</option>
    <option value="7">7 night(s)</option>
    <option value="8">8 night(s)</option>
    <option value="9" selected="selected">9 night(s)</option>
    <option value="10">10 night(s)</option>
    <option value="11">11 night(s)</option>
    <option value="12">12 night(s)</option>
    <option value="13">13 night(s)</option>
    <option value="14">14 night(s)</option>
    <option value="15">15 night(s)</option>
    <option value="16">16 night(s)</option>
    <option value="17">17 night(s)</option>
    <option value="18">18 night(s)</option>
    <option value="19">19 night(s)</option>
    <option value="20">20 night(s)</option>
    <option value="21">21 night(s)</option>
</select>`
 how to track that particular element(eg. option 4).

Comment: what language are you using for selenium?

Comment: as he states - `Selenium IDE`

Answer (score 0):

As I am ignorant of the site you are trying to test, I'll attempt to elaborate what's happening.

This is very common in websites, where the site is dynamic and the ID's get either randomly generated, or changed.   If this happens, you can use the power of CSS selectors to select what you want.

in your case, the **Target** field would be

```
css=div[id^='duration']
```

This would look for a div that has the ID that *starts with* duration.  Ergo, if that `3` in there changes, then it would have no effect.

Comment: But there are multiple div tags having id starting with 'duration', then how to identify that particular id? Can i put multiple attributes to tract those and how to give multiple attributes? Please its urgent

Answer (score 0):

As answered in your other question, If you only want to track an element you can always use "FireBug" at least to inspect the element.